# How does JavaScript "take back" an uncaught Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, microsoft-edge

If I enter the following into the console, no error is reported to the console

```js
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('started')
    reject('immediately reject')
})

console.log('do some other work')

p.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error caught')
})

// Outputs:
// do some other work
// error caught
```

But if I remove the call to `catch` an uncaught error is shown. I can even type in the first half, hit enter, see the error, then add the catch and the error goes away. This seems weird to me: how can JavaScript know that a promise will eventually be caught? How would this affect control flow of an application if there's always a chance a promise could later be caught?

I understand promises are typically for asynchronous code, but one could imagine a promise which may return immediately with a validation error or something.

I am aware of `try`/`catch`, I'm just trying to understand how this works.

Running in Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.59 (64-bit)

Comment: "*how can JavaScript know that a promise will eventually be caught?*" - it doesn't. It only removes the warning from the console **when** you execute the code that adds the promise rejection handler.

Comment: (Btw, the devtools console is unique in that regard as it allows interaction and dynamic removal of messages. Writing the errors to a log file would prevent them from being hidden, see e.g. in nodejs)

Comment: Are you only asking about the dev console?  Or do you want to know about executing a complete script in a full execution environment.  If you only want to know about the dev console, I'll delete my answer because it's a funky environment with all sorts of special behaviors that does not necessarily give you real results when dealing with asynchronous code.

Comment: Just for perspective, in my FF, the error message stays. In my Chrome, the message goes from red to blue. (and JS is not responsible here, don't worry)/

Comment: @adam - As we discussed in chat `p.catch()` returns a new promise that is the result of what happens in the `.catch()` handler so that's a completely different case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just talking about a message you see in the console that then disappears, then this is just something that occurs in a specific Javascript environment where it decides after-the-fact to rescind/remove a debug message in the console.  It does not affect the running of your code in any way.  Try three different browsers and you will see different behaviors in each because what shows in the console and when it shows there is up to the implementor of the engine/console, not something that is standardized or something that affects the outcome of your code.

Beyond that, let's discuss issues related to the timing of when a `.catch()` handler is added.  The rejection of your promise is not processed synchronously.  The promise state is changed immediately internal to the promise, but it does not synchronously call any `.catch()` handlers.  Instead, a job is inserted into the promise job queue and only when the current chunk of Javascript that is executing is finished and returns control back to the event loop does the promise job get to do its work.

So, in your code, the `.catch()` handler is added in the current chunk of Javascript execution BEFORE the promise tries to call its catch handlers.  Thus, when the promise job that contains the rejection does actually get processed, it is not an uncaught promise because the `.catch()` handler is already in place.

---

FYI, typing code into the console and executing it there will not necessarily offer the same timing (and thus errors) as running code in a real script.  My comments above are about what happens if you run your whole script at once.  I always evaluate asynchronous code in a real execution environment running a complete script, not by typing code into a console and running it pieces at a time.

> I can even type in the first half, hit enter, see the error, then add the catch and the error goes away.

That's just a weirdness that occurs in the console when you run pieces of code, but not the whole script.  That is not representative of running the whole code in a script.

> This seems weird to me: how can JavaScript know that a promise will eventually be caught?

It doesn't.  It evaluates whether there's a `.catch()` handler when the rejection is actually processed (which is via the Promise job queue).

> How would this affect control flow of an application if there's always a chance a promise could later be caught?

It's not really an issue because the `.catch()` handler just needs to be in place before control returns to the event loop when the promise is actually rejected.  And, that is usually how code is written so this isn't an issue.  You create the promise (or call a function that returns a promise), then you add handlers to it - all in one body of code.

> I understand promises are typically for asynchronous code, but one could imagine a promise which may return immediately with a validation error or something.

Neither `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers are ever called synchronously, even if the promise is resolved or rejected synchronously.  They are always called via the Promise job queue which is always after the current synchronously running Javascript finishes executing and returns control back to the event loop.

Comment: I appreciate the really thorough response, and per your suggestion I tried dumping the following in a script tag of an HTML file
`let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { console.log('before'); reject('rejected immediately'); }); console.log('after definition'); window.setTimeout(() => p.catch(error => console.log('safely caught:', error)), 1000)`
But the error still appeared and then disappeared after a second.

Comment: @Adam - I'm not going to be able to help with stuff you're doing in the console and frankly it isn't worth spending time on.  Run a full, complete script in nodejs or in the browser.  Errors there don't disappear.  The  console is a "faked" execution environment.  As I said in my answer, you sometimes cannot properly evaluate the timing of asynchronous things in the console.

Comment: I did state in my comment that that code was executed in a script tag of an HTML file. Is that not what you're asking for?

Comment: @Adam - You talked about typing the first half, seeing the error, then typing the second half and seeing the error going away.  That is NOT executing a normal script at all.  That NEVER happens in a web page or in nodejs running a real program.  If that's all you're really asking about, then I'll delete my  answer as the only answer to that is that's how the dev console was written (to retract errors in certain circumstances).

Comment: Yes, in my original question I was typing in the console, but after your answer I tried creating a full HTML file with the script embedded and examining the output. See this [complete example](https://pastebin.com/0XX8N8A6). The error still appears and disappears from the console even though it came from a script tag.

Comment: @Adam - That's just a particular implementation detail of the communication between the JS engine and the console in that particular browser.  It has NOTHING at all to do with the execution of your code and how your code behaves.  So, you're deep diving on a particular console behavior that is how one particular JS environment chooses to display things in the console.  It does not affect how your code runs.  If this is not a satisfactory answer for you, then I can delete my question.  Go check out several other browsers and you will see several DIFFERENT implementations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234308/discussion-between-adam-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @Adam - The console itself, what it displays in cases like this and when it displays things is not covered in any specification - it's purely up to the implementor how they want to implement it as it's just meant as an aid to developers.